# Send IP Address in email with node.js

Tags: email, node.js, ip-address

So I'm trying to send myself my IP address through node.js and so far have come up empty handed.  So far my code looks like this:

```
var exec = require("child_process").exec;
var ipAddress = exec("ifconfig | grep -m 1 inet", function (error, stdout, stderr) {
   ipAddress = stdout;
});
var email = require('nodemailer');

email.SMTP = {
   host: 'smtp.gmail.com',
   port: 465,
   ssl: true,
   user_authentication: true,
   user: 'sendingemail@gmail.com',
   pass: 'mypass'
}

email.send_mail({
   sender: 'sendingemail@gmail.com',
   to: 'receivingemail@gmail.com',
   subject: 'Testing!',
   body: 'IP Address of the machine is ' + ipAddress
   },
   function(error, success) {
       console.log('Message ' + success ? 'sent' : 'failed');
               console.log('IP Address is ' + ipAddress);
               process.exit();
   }
);
```

So far it is sending the email but it never inserts the IP address.  It puts the appropriate IP address in the console log that I can see, but cannot get it to send in an email.  Can anyone help me see what I am doing wrong in my code?

Comment: Why are you using "exec" instead of `os.networkInterfaces` which is cross-os?

Source: http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/os.html#os_os_networkinterfaces

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because the `send_mail` function starts before the `exec` has returned the ip.

So just start sending the mail once exec has returned the ip.

This should work:

```
var exec = require("child_process").exec;
var ipAddress;
var child = exec("ifconfig | grep -m 1 inet", function (error, stdout, stderr) {
   ipAddress = stdout;
   start();
});
var email = require('nodemailer');

function start(){

    email.SMTP = {
       host: 'smtp.gmail.com',
       port: 465,
       ssl: true,
       user_authentication: true,
       user: 'sendingemail@gmail.com',
       pass: 'mypass'
    }

    email.send_mail({
       sender: 'sendingemail@gmail.com',
       to: 'receivingemail@gmail.com',
       subject: 'Testing!',
       body: 'IP Address of the machine is ' + ipAddress
       },
       function(error, success) {
           console.log('Message ' + success ? 'sent' : 'failed');
                   console.log('IP Address is ' + ipAddress);
                   process.exit();
       }
    );
}
```

Comment: Yep, this works like a charm!  Thanks a ton, as you might be able to tell I really have no idea what I am doing with node.js :-)